# JWNL for word stemming

Tags: java, wordnet

i am trying to stem a word using the code below  but it gives a exception.

```
  public class stemmer {

 private int MaxWordLength = 50;
private Dictionary dic;
private MorphologicalProcessor morph;
private boolean IsInitialized = false;  
public HashMap AllWords = null;

public stemmer()
{

    AllWords = new HashMap ();

    try
    {
                System.out.println ("1" );
        JWNL.initialize(new FileInputStream
            ("D:\\azeema\\MyResearch\\words database\\jwnl14-rc2 javaAPI\\jwnl14-rc2\\config/file_properties.xml"));
        dic = Dictionary.getInstance();
        morph = dic.getMorphologicalProcessor();
        // ((AbstractCachingDictionary)dic).
        //  setCacheCapacity (10000);
        IsInitialized = true;
                    System.out.println ("2" );
    }
    catch ( FileNotFoundException e )
    {
               // System.out.println (e);
        System.out.println ( "Error initializing Stemmer: JWNLproperties.xml not found" );
    }
    catch ( JWNLException e )
    {

        System.out.println ( "Error initializing Stemmer: " 
            + e.toString() );
                     e.printStackTrace();
    } 

}

public void Unload ()
{ 
    dic.close();
    Dictionary.uninstall();
    JWNL.shutdown();
}
public String StemWordWithWordNet ( String word )
{
    if ( !IsInitialized )
        return word;
    if ( word == null ) return null;
    if ( morph == null ) morph = dic.getMorphologicalProcessor();

    IndexWord w;
    try
    {
        w = morph.lookupBaseForm( POS.VERB, word );
        if ( w != null )
            return w.getLemma().toString ();
        w = morph.lookupBaseForm( POS.NOUN, word );
        if ( w != null )
            return w.getLemma().toString();
        w = morph.lookupBaseForm( POS.ADJECTIVE, word );
        if ( w != null )
            return w.getLemma().toString();
        w = morph.lookupBaseForm( POS.ADVERB, word );
        if ( w != null )
            return w.getLemma().toString();
    } 
    catch ( JWNLException e )
    {
                System.out.println (e);
    }
    return null;
}


  }
```

this is code for word stemming, when i run this code i found this exception

```
      run:
```

1
Error initializing Stemmer: net.didion.jwnl.JWNLException: Unable to install net.didion.jwnl.dictionary.FileBackedDictionary
net.didion.jwnl.JWNLException: Unable to install net.didion.jwnl.dictionary.FileBackedDictionary
    at net.didion.jwnl.util.factory.Element.install(Element.java:34)
    at net.didion.jwnl.JWNL.initialize(JWNL.java:157)
    at opennlp.stemmer.(stemmer.java:29)
    at opennlp.OpenNLP.main(OpenNLP.java:28)
Caused by: net.didion.jwnl.JWNLException: The properties file must specify a dictionary path
    at net.didion.jwnl.util.factory.AbstractValueParam.create(AbstractValueParam.java:34)
    at net.didion.jwnl.dictionary.FileBackedDictionary.install(FileBackedDictionary.java:100)
    at net.didion.jwnl.util.factory.Element.install(Element.java:32)
    ... 3 more
Caused by: net.didion.jwnl.JWNLException: Could not create a file manager of type class net.didion.jwnl.princeton.file.PrincetonRandomAccessDictionaryFile
    at net.didion.jwnl.dictionary.file_manager.FileManagerImpl.create(FileManagerImpl.java:71)
    at net.didion.jwnl.util.factory.AbstractValueParam.create(AbstractValueParam.java:32)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Program Files (x86)\WordNet\2.1\dict\verb.idx (The system cannot find the file specified)
    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.(RandomAccessFile.java:241)
    at net.didion.jwnl.princeton.file.PrincetonRandomAccessDictionaryFile.openFile(PrincetonRandomAccessDictionaryFile.java:76)
    at net.didion.jwnl.dictionary.file.AbstractDictionaryFile.open(AbstractDictionaryFile.java:58)
    at net.didion.jwnl.dictionary.file.DictionaryCatalog.open(DictionaryCatalog.java:46)
    at net.didion.jwnl.dictionary.file.DictionaryCatalogSet.open(DictionaryCatalogSet.java:34)
    at net.didion.jwnl.dictionary.file_manager.FileManagerImpl.(FileManagerImpl.java:54)
    at net.didion.jwnl.dictionary.file_manager.FileManagerImpl.create(FileManagerImpl.java:69)
    ... 6 more
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)

Comment: Giving the full stack trace and not only the `exception.toString()` might better help identifying the problem.

Comment: seems like you have the wrong path for the dictionary "C:\Program Files (x86)\WordNet\2.1\dict\verb.idx"

Comment: if you are sure your have the correct path to the directory contain verb file, check the version number in file_properties.xml. It might be set to 2.0 instead of 3.0. Also, check if you have the files in the form "index.verb" or "verb.idx". You then have two choices, either change the version, or change the files.

Comment: i am using wordnet-2.0 so it should be 2.0 in file_properties.xml? .. I should also change dictionary_path in map_properties.xml??